# Efficient way to group indices of the same elements in a list

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Let's say I have a list that looks like:

```
[1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 3, 9, 0, 1]
```

Now I want to group the indices of the same elements, so the result should look like:

```
[[0, 9], [1, 2], [3], [4], [5, 6], [7], [8]]
```

How do I do this in an efficient way? I try to avoid using loops so any implementations using numpy/pandas functions are great.

Comment: numpy.argsort followed by one pass over indices (referencing array elements) to group them (break group on different element). or use itertools.groupby for the second step.

Comment: Can you specify "one pass over indices" by giving some code example?@randomir

Comment: Is the order important? Also, where is your attempt?

Comment: "I try to avoid using loops" - why?

Comment: @cs95 The order doesn't actually matter. I tried my best but couldn't come up with a fine implementation(even by using loops) so had to ask here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using pandas `GroupBy.apply`, this is pretty straightforward—use your data to group on a Series of indices. A nice bonus here is you get to keep the order of your indices.

```
data = [1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 3, 9, 0, 1]
pd.Series(range(len(data))).groupby(data, sort=False).apply(list).tolist()
# [[0, 9], [1, 2], [3], [4], [5, 6], [7], [8]]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group indices:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 3, 9, 0, 1]

d = defaultdict(list)
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    d[x].append(i)

print(list(d.values()))
# [[0, 9], [1, 2], [3], [4], [5, 6], [7], [8]]
```

Which also maintains order of indices added without sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a modification of hash counting but instead of counting, just store the index of the value found.

```
arr = [1,2,2,5,8,3,3,9,0,1]
d = dict()  
for i,v in enumerate(arr):  
    d[v] = d.get(v,[]) #use an if-statement to avoid doing this too often
    d[v].append(i) 
print(d.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to "avoid loops", since there's no way of knowing the functions you're calling aren't using loops anyway, adding the overhead of a function call.

Also, after grouping, you lose information about what it is grouping - so putting the output in a `dict` seems to make more sense.

This does that:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 3, 9, 0, 1]
result = {
    key: [item[0] for item in group]
    for key, group in groupby(sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1]), lambda x: x[1])
}

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{0: [8], 1: [0, 9], 2: [1, 2], 3: [5, 6], 5: [3], 8: [4], 9: [7]}
```

Comment: I actually have to solve the same problem on a much larger dataset. So far as I know, pandas/numpy implementations save more when dealing with large amount of data. Please correct me if this is not true.

Comment: Most solutions will end up loading the entire data set in memory anyway. The main concern would then be to avoid creating too many additional copies of the data in memory. The solution I'm giving doesn't create superfluous copies beyond the one copy in results, as the used elements all use generators. However, the solution you're asking for doesn't seem to be very much aligned with large data sets to begin with. What exactly do you consider 'large' in this context?

Comment: I have a Pandas dataframe that has ~32k rows and 9 columns. The index grouping is applied along each column so I'd say it's a list having ~32k elements