# lookup function for repeated elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, big-o

I have a list-like python object of positive integers and I want to get which locations on that list have repeated values. For example
if input is `[0,1,1]` the function should return `[1,2]` because the value of 1, which is the element at position 1 and 2 of the input array appears twice. Similarly:

`[0,13,13]` should return `[[1, 2]]`

`[0,1,2,1,3,4,2,2]` should return `[[1, 3], [2, 6, 7]]` because `1` appears twice, at positions [1, 3] of the input array and `2` appears 3 times at positions [2, 6, 7]

`[1, 2, 3]` should return an empty array `[]`

What I have written is this:

```
def get_locations(labels):
    out = []
    label_set = set(labels)
    for label in list(label_set):
        temp = [i for i, j in enumerate(labels) if j == label]
        if len(temp) > 1:
            out.append(np.array(temp))

    return np.array(out)
```

While it works ok for small input arrays it gets too slow when size grows. For instance, The code below on my pc, skyrockets from `0.14secs` when `n=1000` to `12secs` when `n = 10000`

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
n = 10000
a = np.arange(n)
b = np.append(a, a[-1]) # append the last element to the end
out = get_locations(b)
end = timer()
print(out)
print(end - start) # Time in seconds
```

How can I speed this up please? Any ideas highly appreciated

Comment: A very similar question: [Efficient way to group indices of the same elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56641420/7851470)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is slow because of the nested for-loop. You can solve this in a more efficient way by using another data structure:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mylist = [0,1,2,1,3,4,2,2]

output = defaultdict(list)
# Loop once over mylist, store the indices of all unique elements
for i, el in enumerate(mylist):
    output[el].append(i)

# Filter out elements that occur only once
output = {k:v for k, v in output.items() if len(v) > 1}
```

This produces the following output for your example `b`:

```
{1: [1, 3], 2: [2, 6, 7]}
```

You can turn this result into the desired format:

```
list(output.values())
> [[1, 3], [2, 6, 7]]
```

Know however that this relies on the dictionary being insertion ordered, which is only the case as of python 3.6.

Comment: Many thanks everyone. blhsing's and Vicrobot's suggestion are quite similar to this one..I wish I could accept all three The way you guys did this, didnt really cross my mind and looks quite simple. Many thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Your nested loop results in *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity. You can instead create a dict of lists to map indices to each label, and extract the sub-lists of the dict only if the length of the sub-list is greater than 1, which reduces the time complexity to *O(n)*:

```
def get_locations(labels):
    positions = {}
    for index, label in enumerate(labels):
        positions.setdefault(label, []).append(index)
    return [indices for indices in positions.values() if len(indices) > 1]
```

so that `get_locations([0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2])` returns:

```
[[1, 3], [2, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: Perhaps it's good to mention that this solution depends on the dictionary being insertion ordered, which is the case as of python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a code i implemented. It runs in linear time:

```
l = [0,1,2,1,3,4,2,2]
dict1 = {}

for j,i in enumerate(l): # O(n)
    temp = dict1.get(i) # O(1) most cases
    if not temp:
        dict1[i] = [j]
    else:
        dict1[i].append(j) # O(1) 

print([item for item in dict1.values() if len(item) > 1]) # O(n)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3], [2, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is essentially a [time-complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) issue. Your algorithm has nested for loops that iterate through the list twice, so the time complexity is of the order of n^2, where n is the size of the list. So when you multiply the size of the list by 10 (from 1,000 to 10,000), you see an approximate time increase of 10^2 = 100. This is why it goes from 0.14 s to 12 s.

Here is a simple solution with no extra libraries required:

```
def get_locations(labels):
    locations = {}
    for index, label in enumerate(labels):
        if label in locations:
            locations[label].append(index)
        else:
            locations[label] = [index]

    return [locations[i] for i in locations if len(locations[i]) > 1]
```

Since the for loops are not nested, the time complexity is approximately 2n, so you should see about a 4-times increase in time whenever the problem size is doubled.

Answer (score -2):

you can try using "Counter" function from "collections" module

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = [1,1,2,3,4,4,4]
Counter(list1)
```

you will get an output similar to this

```
Counter({4: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1})
```